# How can I execute a function from my navigation menu without using a controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service, hook

I'm working on a project and I need to be able to execute a function from my app's navigation menu. As far as I understand, all functions are executable from a view using wire:click, and this triggers the function from the associated controller.

Is there any way to create a global function (or several) so that they can be called from the navigation menu (which is always loaded) regardless of the view I'm in?

I hope I've explained myself.

I've tried to use Ajax, Providers, and more, but I don't know which is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I've done this in my laravel project (I'm not using livewire though, but I don't see why this won't work for you).

Create a service provider if you don't have one for your site/app

```
php artisan make:provider SiteServiceProvider
```

Register the service provider in `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
        // other service providers
        App\Providers\SiteServiceProvider::class,
    ])->toArray(),
```

And in the `boot` method of your `SiteServiceProvider` you can make global functions (available within all of your views)

```
View::share('formatPhoneNumber', function ($phoneNumber) {
    // Ensure $phoneNumber is a 10-digit number
    $phoneNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phoneNumber);

    // Format the phone number
    return sprintf("(%s) %s - %s",
        substr($phoneNumber, 0, 3),
        substr($phoneNumber, 3, 3),
        substr($phoneNumber, 6)
    );
});
```

And in your view you can use that function like so

```
<a class="stretched-link" href="tel:{{ $phoneNumber }}">&#x260E; {{ $formatPhoneNumber($phoneNumber) }}</a>
```

You could also make global variables.

In the `boot` method of that `SiteServiceProvider` you would have something like the following

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) use ($config) {
    $view->with('phoneNumber', $config['phoneNumber']);
    $view->with('emailAddress', $config['emailAddress']);
    // Add more variables as needed
});
```

And then you can use it in the view like

```
<a class="stretched-link" href="tel:{{ $phoneNumber }}">&#x260E; {{ $formatPhoneNumber($phoneNumber) }}</a>
```

Having written most of this answer I now realize that this is not what you meant, you want to invoke a function by using a menu from anywhere in the site regardless of the view being served, but since I've already written this answer, maybe it'll be useful to others...

One way you probably might be able to do this is putting the functions you want to be global into a trait, and then using that trait in all your view component classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire off livewire events a number of ways but what i think you want is here;

```
// Dispatch an event to any Livewire components listening...
Livewire.dispatch('post-created', { postId: 2 })

// Dispatch an event to a given Livewire component by name...
Livewire.dispatchTo('dashboard', 'post-created', { postId: 2 })
```

Full documentation around these function can be found here [The livewire global object](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/javascript#the-livewire-global-object)

Make sure your components are listening for the events!

```
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On; // this line is important

class Dashboard extends Component
{
    #[On('post-created')] // also this line is important
    public function updatePostList($title)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```